# How to implement a Fish-Eye projection of an image on a planar surface using OpenGL

Tags: opengl, projection, fisheye

I need to project a 2D image  on to a 2D planar surface using OpenGL with the Fish-Eye effect.
How can I change the image with the fish-eye projection and map it to the 2d surface?